# Pandas read_csv specifying datatype without knowing column name/number

Tags: pandas

I am trying to import a series of csv files. 
Most of them will have fields that are alphanumeric and some that are a mixture of interger and missing. Pandas automatically imports these datatypes as Object and Float64, but I would like them to imported as strings and integers respectively. I know how to specify the datatype for specific columns, but can I stipulate the behaviour that I want at the import stage. 
I know that columns can be converted once imported but that won't work for me.

Comment: integers cannot represent missing values so your latter requirement will not work, also `object` is the correct `dtype` for `string`, this just means `python object`

Comment: ok, basically I was getting this error on import: 

DtypeWarning: Columns (3,26,71,92,114,119) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

And converting the problem columns individually to strings fixed it. The problem is I won't always know which columns have mixed types, so I want to be able stipulate that any mixed type be represented as a string.

The other problem is that all the integer fields are being represented as floats. I thought that this might be because some of the values are blank, but I'm not sure.